# Login and Oauth in Android Studio and Jax-rs

Tags: android, web-services, oauth, jwt

im developing an android app and I connect to services to authenticate the user.....
So do you recomend to use JWT and OAuth for security in my android app, I have the rest services in Java with Jax-rs and jersey.